# Process has died/Scheduling restart of crashed service

Tags: android, service, crash

I have a service which is also LocationListener. Upon new location event it performes some kind of network stuff which can take time; that's why it is implemented as AsyncTask.

Often I see in log on the real device:

```
03-29 17:02:20.847 D/dalvikvm(  235): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 961K, 29% free 10234K/14215K, paused 26ms
03-29 17:02:20.855 I/DemoService(  555): DiyScheduer.onStart
03-29 17:02:20.855 I/ggheart (  555): onStart
03-29 17:02:21.097 V/PhoneStatusBar(  235): setLightsOn(true)
03-29 17:02:21.121 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11244): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-29 17:02:21.277 I/ActivityManager(  161): Process android.process.media (pid 11298) has died.
03-29 17:02:22.058 I/ActivityManager(  161): Process com.idavydov.myapp (pid 11051) has died.
03-29 17:02:22.066 I/WindowManager(  161): WIN DEATH: Window{41b05850 com.idavydov.myapp/com.idavydov.myapp.MyActivity paused=false}
03-29 17:02:22.074 W/ActivityManager(  161): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.idavydov.myapp/.MyService in 5000ms
```

Usually it happens after some large application is loaded.

Is the reason for this low memory? In that case why there is no such kind of message in log?

P.S. In other question I saw explanation that the reason is that the task takes too much time. But I've added the folowing code to my AsyncTask and couldn't reproduce the crash in the emulator.

```
    protected Boolean doInBackground(...) {
        ...
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - time < 11 * 1000);
        ....
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Your process dies each time you're running your doInBackground?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixing two things.
Android doesnt allow blocking the UI thread, and it will kill your app if so. Unless you put the blocking processing and loops into the background process of AsyncTask.

Beside of this, android will kill your app without any warning when it has low memory or it identifies that your app has no effect on the user.
If you want your app to stay longer, you'll need a sticky service and a good app lifecycle managment.

Comment: Is there a way to identify the reason why the service was killed?

Comment: @IakovDavydov maybe if you get a device log

Comment: Small fragment is presented in the question. But I don't see anything related to my service near that time.

Comment: I see that your using async tasks, so I doubt it's because of blocking ui thread. I had similar problems when turning wi-fi on device, and also when I was having to complex animation. On some Android versions you wont see the reason in logs, what target are you using?

Comment: Android 4.0.3 (API Level 15). Also according to the log AsyncTask finishes succesfully and after that sometimes service dies (not often; usually if i launch some other app).
Also if this is a resources issue why are they using words "dies" and "crashed" instead of "killed"? :)